# ASP.NET Web Application Times out after 20 minutes

Tags: asp.net, iis, timeout

We have a web application that makes heavy use of session state and uses forms authentication. The application is dumping the user back out to the login screen after 20 minutes. The way the application works is it puts a value in the session state when the session starts and every time a postback occurs or a different .aspx page runs, it checks to see if that value is still there. If it isn't there (the session expired) it automatically logs you out. I did not design it this way. The application was already here when I got here. Anyway, we decided that 20 minutes was not enough time and wanted to increase it to an hour. But no matter what we set the timeout property in the authentication/forms and the system.web/sessionState to, it continues to log out after 20 minutes. Why does it not seem to care what timeout values I specify? Is there a global setting somewhere that might be overriding it?

Comment: The default timeout value for asp.net session is 20 minutes. See this msdn link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.80).aspx. Can you share how and where are you setting a custom timeout value ?

Comment: I'm setting it in the web.config file

<sessionState cookieless="false" cookieName=".IVSTEST" mode="InProc" timeout="180" /> 

for the sessionstate and

<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="180" protection="All" path="/" />

for the authenticatino cookie.

Right now its set to 2 hours or 180 minutes in both places.

Comment: Does the app domain recycle?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea.

Comment: So by default, IIS will shut down the app domain (the process your site lives in) after a certain period of no incoming requests (I believe default is 20 minutes). To test if that's what's happening, add some logging to your Application_Start method in your global application class (global.asax or global.asax.cs). The logging could be as simple as writing `"Application Started: " + DateTime.Now` to a text file somewhere. Perhaps if you do that you may see that the app domain goes down, then your client makes a new request, at which point it's new session (because you don't persist the session)

Comment: You can try setting the `Session.Timeout = 180` in the `Session_Start` event in `Global.asax.vb/cs`

Comment: mason, Is this the Idle Timeout property in the Process Model section of the advanced settings of the application pool?

Comment: @MichaelS.Miller - yes

Comment: Okay mason, kev, setting the Timeout property in the process model section solved the problem.